# Fetch PHP SOAP request data

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a page which will receive data directly from a SOAP request. The problem is "How will I receive that data?". If data is coming directly in `$_GET` parameter, I can fetch via `$_GET['PARAM']`, but how will I fetch data here as it is coming directly in SOAP?

I have a WSDL file, NotificationToCP.wsdl as well.

Following is the SOAP request.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sub="http://example.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <sub:handleNewSubscription>
        <custAttributesDTO>
            <cpId>{$cpId}</cpId>
            <cpPwd>{$cpPwd}</cpPwd>
            <productId>{$productId}</productId>
            <channelName>{$channelName}</channelName>
            <contentProvider>{$contentProvider}</contentProvider>
            <cpName>{$cpName}</cpName>
            <firstConfirmationDTTM>{$firstConfirmationDTTM}</firstConfirmationDTTM>
            <secondConfirmationDTTM>{$secondConfirmationDTTM}</secondConfirmationDTTM>
        </custAttributesDTO>
    </sub:handleNewSubscription>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to fetch this SOAP request data with following code.

```
$client = new SoapClient($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/NotificationToCP.wsdl", array('trace' => true));
var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: You are not even calling the function. Check out the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: If I call this $client->__soapCall(), how will I retrieve the values mentioned above in the SOAP request?

Comment: `$response = $client ->__soapCall();
print_r($response);`

Answer (score 0):

What you are returning from the `SOAP` call is an Object and you cannot print an Object you need to pull the value of the property of that object that stores your return value that you can then print. So in the `SOAP XML` where your response tag is, use the value of that tag and then:

`print_r($result->name_Of_Tag_In_XML);`